# How do warnings on undefined selectors work in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compiler-warnings

Is there any way to make the compiler raise a warning when calling a selector that is not defined ? For example, I have this call somewhere :

```
methodcall time1:[[self.H1time copy] stringValue]
```

stringValue method does not exist anymore in the H1time class and the compiler did not raise anything.

copyWithZone is declared as

```
- (NSHour*)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
```

The compiler raises a warning inside NSHour if I call `[self stringValue]`.
but not in `methodcall time1:[[self.H1time copy] stringValue]`

I saw this miss only because of an intensive test followed with a crash.

I'd like the compiler prevent me of such wrong calls.
How may I do this ?

Some tests that says that the compiler may warn in the above case :

```
NSHour *titi = [NSHour hourWithString:@"00:00:00"];
    id toto = [titi copy];
NSString *str2 = [toto doThis];  --- Warning : "No doThis Method found"
```

Another test :

```
NSHour *titi = [NSHour hourWithString:@"00:00:00"];
NSString *str3 = [[titi copy] doThis];  --- Warning : "No doThis Method found"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the compiler to warn you, cast the object returned by `-copy` to the type you’re expecting, e.g.

```
[(NSHour *)[self.H1time copy] stringValue]
```

(by the way, I wouldn’t use the NS prefix for my classes since it’s a prefix used by Apple.)

As others have stated, `-copy` is declared as returning a value of type `id`. Since `id` denotes a generic object, the compiler doesn’t have any information as to which selectors the return value can respond to. It does know that there exists a `stringValue` selector (because a few Cocoa classes declare `-stringValue` methods), so it accepts that.

**But I’ve overridden `-copyWithZone:` to return NSHour *!**

And that’s the right thing to do if you need custom copying behaviour since `-copy` is just a convenience method that invokes `-copyWithZone:`. However, as stated above, your code invokes `-copy`, which hasn’t been overriden to return `NSHour *`.

**What if I also override `-copy` so that it returns NSHour *?**

Then the compiler would know that and would warn you in case you’re trying to send a message containing a selector that has no corresponding method in `NSHour`.

**Should I do this?**

Well, for the most part, not really.

Have you ever wondered why all examples of overriding `-init` return `id` instead of a class type? This happens because the Objective-C runtime creates a single method description for a given selector. Consequently, methods in different classes having same selectors (i.e., same method names) should share the same argument types and return types.

So, from the runtime perspective, the selector `init` is described as a method with that name and return type `id`. Similarly, the selector `copy` is described as a method with that name and return type `id`. If you reuse a selector name in methods with different return types or argument types, you’re confusing the runtime system, which could cause a crash or data being mangled.

That being said, when you’re statically typing your objects, you’re giving information to the compiler so that it knows which methods are available, and it will use the appropriate methods regardless of methods in other classes having different return types and argument types.

[This thread on cocoabuilder.com](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/286017-why-doesn-the-compiler-complain.html) has more information on the subject, including a reply by Greg Parker, who works on the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `copyWithZone:` method seems to be defined to return `id` in [`NSCopying`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) zone;
```

And so is the convenience `copy` method of [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (id) copy;
```

You don’t get warning for the `stringValue` message because the receiver is `id` (= any object) and there is a `stringValue` message defined somewhere (like on `NSNumber`). On the other hand there is no `doThis` defined anywhere, so that the compiler can be reasonably sure that’s probably a typo, regardless of the receiver type. (And if you insist, you can always call `performSelector:` to get rid of the warning.)

The strange thing is the compiler letting you get away with a `copyWithZone:` with a different type signature. Maybe your parent already implements `NSCopying` and your `copyWithZone:` version is simply skipped because of the different signature?

Comment: Maybe the `id` type is special with respect to overriding, might be worth a test.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer assumed copy was returning an object of type id, which isn't the case, so doesn't apply here.

---

Firstly, it's important to understand that in Objective-C you *send messages* not *call methods*. This is a very important distinction, because it means the target of the message (in this case 'stringValue') is resolved **at runtime**.

When you call:

```
[self stringValue]
```

...XCode is clever enough to figure out that 'self' doesn't respond to the 'stringValue' message, because the message *receiver* is the same object as the message *sender*.. But when you call:

```
[[self.H1time copy] stringValue]
```

...XCode *doesn't know* what [self.H1time copy] will resolve to until runtime. The system doesn't know in advance what [self.H1time copy] will respond to, so you don't get a compiler warning.

This seems odd, but is by design. It's one of the big differences between Objective-C and C++. So I don't believe (and I'm happy to be proven wrong) that you can have a warning on an unknown selector, because of Obj-C's *message centric* design.

Comment: @lxt : You're wrong. Make some tests. ANyway, copyWithZone returns a Typed object. I send a message that is not references on this typed object. In other situations, the compiler warns me, but not here.

Comment: NSString *str3 = [[titi copy] doThis]; raises a warning.

Comment: Funny thing, the warning is "No doThis METHOD found" :-)  Apple made a mistake here ?

Comment: Ah, OK - I was assuming you were using an untyped copy (NSObject, which I guess you're inheriting from, will return id for copy/copyWithZone). I have edited the answer to reflect the mistake. Apologies :)

Comment: And with id toto = [titi copy];
 
 NSString *str = [toto doThis]; the compiler warns "No doThis Method found"

Comment: @lxt : So could you delete this answer please ?