# Objective C block declarations conflict

Tags: iphone, objective-c, typedef, objective-c-blocks

I've encountered some really annoying issue about objective c blocks. Let's say, we have a code like this:

```
//Class1.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^Class1Callback)(BOOL bl);

@interface Class1 : NSObject { }

- (id)initWithCallback:(Class1Callback)callback;

@end

//Class2.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum Class2Enum { Foo, Bar, FooBar } Class2Enum;

typedef void (^Class2Callback)(Class2Enum ce);

@interface Class2 : NSObject { }

- (id)initWithCallback:(Class2Callback)callback;

@end

//main.c
#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Class1 *class1 = [[Class1 alloc] initWithCallback:^(BOOL bl){ }];
    Class2 *class2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithCallback:^(Class2Enum ce){ }];
}
```

In this code I'm getting an error "incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)(enum Class2Enum)', expected 'Class1Callback'" in line

```
Class2 *class2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithCallback:^(Class2Enum ce){ }];
```

But when I just reverse imports in main.c, ie

```
#import "Class2.h"
#import "Class1.h"
```

error changes its place and description - now it's in line

```
Class1 *class1 = [[Class1 alloc] initWithCallback:^(BOOL bl){ }];
```

and description is "incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)(BOOL)', expected 'Class2Callback'"

Why does the compiler expect 'Class2Callback' when the method's declaration says that the block type is Class1Callback?
I have no idea why it's happening and where I should seek and what I should read to find the answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+alloc` returns an `id`, which is the generic object type in Objective-C. Because of that, the compiler does not know which `-initWithCallback:` you mean, since that `id` could in theory be an instance of either of your classes. You must cast the result of the `+alloc` call to the class you're instantiating in cases of conflict like this:

```
Class1 *class1 = [(Class1 *)[Class1 alloc] initWithCallback: ...];
```

Alternatively, rename your initialization methods so they aren't identical, and the compiler will be able to distinguish them. Try something more descriptive, if you can:

```
- (id)initWithCompletionHandler: (Class1Callback)handler;
- (id)initWithProgressHandler: (Class2Callback)handler;
```

Comment: I've answered a related question the OP might want to read as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705567/how-do-warnings-on-undefined-selectors-work-in-objective-c/4706071#4706071

Comment: Thanks, I've completely forgotten about id in alloc return. As for the naming - it was just for example, though in my real code I need my init methods to have identical names.

Comment: @Alexander In general, having different methods with same names (i.e., same name/same selector but different return/argument types) is not advisable because the runtime keeps only one method description for a given selector. See the question that I linked in my first comment.